# Count the occurrence of a specific character in all elements of a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list:

```
my_list = ['coffee', 'sunshine', 'hiking', 'stocks', 'mountains', 'space', 'Travel']
```

I would like to count the occurrence of a specific letter across all the elements in that list, let's say the letter 's'.

Can this be achieved without loops?

Comment: `collections.Counter("".join(my_list))["s"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the words, you then get a string where you can use the count() method to get the number of occurence of a letter.

```py
"".join(my_list).count("a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function provided you want the count of the character in each string in the given list.

```py
my_list = ['coffee', 'sunshine', 'hiking', 'stocks', 'mountains', 'space', 'Travel']

count_s = list(map(lambda n: n.count('s'), my_list))
print(count_s)

[0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Better to avoid `map(lambda)...` - instead you could do this ```[w.count('s') for w in lst]```